# Simple Insert Query is resulting in Msg 10054

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am simply trying to Insert some records into the SQL Server 2008 as follows:

```
INSERT INTO [Mydb].[mytable].[Daily_message] (
       [ServerIP_vch]
      ,[ENASubject_vch]
      ,[ENAMessage_vch]
      ,[TroubleshootingTips_vch]
      ,[CGIDump_txt]
      ,[HighPriority_bit]
      ,[AlertType_si]
      ,[Timestamp_dt]
      ,[To_vch])
VALUES
      ('xx.xx.x.xxx',
       'Communication Link Failure',
       'S108',
       'NULL',
       'NULL',
       'CGI DUMP',
       '0',
       '1',
       '2013-10-18 08:02:55.113',
       'my@myemail.com');
```

I received the following message in red color:

```
Msg 10054, Level 20, State 0, Line 0
A transport-level error has occurred when sending the request to the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)
```

I found people discussing about Msg 10054 online here :http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic484875-146-1.aspx

where they are talking about the following causes:

1. network glitches
2. SQL glitches
3. SQL config
4. hostile code

However, I am wondering, how can just a simple Insert query would not run because of the above 4 causes. Anyone has any idea? Please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: This has nothing to do with the SQL statement, and everything to do with the connection (I think).  I suppose there could be a hack somewhere that closes a connection based on the SQL code being passed, but that is highly unlikely.  Try to connect again and run another query.

Comment: Are you using SSMS?  If so, right click your query workspace, click disconnect, then right click again and click connect, choose your database and re-run.  We get this error any time a server has been restarted while we had SSMS open.

Comment: @EvanL Yes, I am using SSMS and simply trying to run the query inside it and when I click on Execute button the error is displayed.

Comment: @John did you try my solution?  Or if that isn't working, just click New Query and cut/paste your code and try again?

Comment: @EvanL Actually I waited for sometime and then executed the query and it worked fine. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Transport-level error Msg 10054, Level 20 will be the displayed error message when the database is being restored from a backup.

For example if it's a development database and the production database is backed up. Then the development database is being updated to the most recent snapshot of the production database & during that time the query is executed this error will occur.

Answer (score 0):

This error will show if a connection is drawn from the connection pool and the connection to the server has been lost.